# scala MongoDB update with $cond and $not with $set and $setOnInsert together

Tags: java, mongodb, scala

I have a problem using a statement to update root fields and an array at the same time. Statement in Mongo:

```
db.getCollection('prueba').update(
{"cdAccount": "ES3100810348150001326934"},
[{"$set": {"camp1": {"$cond": [{"$not": ["$camp1"]}, "values", "$camp1"]}, "cdAcctCurrency": "LIB"}, "$setOnInsert": {"arCtBDFrame": [{"cdEntitFrame": "01", "cdProductFrame": "BD"}]}}]);

A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.
```

It seems that this is due to the $cond operator and because i am updating an array, if I remove the array (arCtBDFrame), I don't see the error. The Scala code that does the same:

```
  def appendIfNotNull(key: String,value :Object) = {
      var eq2Array = new util.ArrayList[Object]()
      eq2Array.add("$"+key)
      val eq2Op = new Document("$not", eq2Array)
      var condList = new util.ArrayList[Object]()
      condList.add(eq2Op)
      condList.add(value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
      //condList.add("$"+key)
      condList.add("value2")
      val availDoc =
        new Document("$cond",
          new Document("$cond", condList)).toBsonDocument(classOf[BsonDocument],getCodecRegistry).get("$cond")
      println("availDoc : " + availDoc)
      documentGrab.append(key,availDoc)
    }
 

       val finalVar = appendIfNotNull("camp1","values")
        println("finalVar : " + finalVar)

availDoc : {"$cond": [{"$not": ["$camp1"]}, "values", "value2"]}
finalVar : Document{{camp1={"$cond": [{"$not": ["$camp1"]}, "values", "value2"]}}}

val arrayBDFrame =
  new Document()
    .append("cdEntitFrame", "01")
    .append("cdProductFrame", "BD")

//val updateDocument = new Document("$set" , finalVar )
val updateDocument =
  new Document()
    .append("$set", finalVar)
    .append("$setOnInsert", new Document()
  .append("arCtBDFrame", java.util.Arrays.asList(arrayBDFrame)))

println("updateDocument (Lista)  : " + Collections.singletonList(updateDocument))

updateDocument (Lista)  : [Document{{$set=Document{{camp1={"$cond": [{"$not": ["$camp1"]}, "values", "$camp1"]}, cdAcctCurrency=LIB}}, $setOnInsert=Document{{arCtBDFrame=[Document{{cdEntitFrame=01, cdProductFrame=BD}}]}}}}]
updateDocument (Lista json)  : [{"$set": {"camp1": {"$cond": [{"$not": ["$camp1"]}, "values", "$camp1"]}, "cdAcctCurrency": "LIB"}, "$setOnInsert": {"arCtBDFrame": [{"cdEntitFrame": "01", "cdProductFrame": "BD"}]}}]

collectionA.updateMany(Filters.eq("cdAccount", "ES3100810348150001326934"),Collections.singletonList(updateDocument))
```

it shows the same error:

Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 40323 (Location40323): 'A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.", "code": 40323, "codeName": "Location40323"}
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175)

But if I remove or comment out the $setOnInsert part, it works fine

```
    //val updateDocument = new Document("$set" , finalVar )
    val updateDocument =
      new Document()
        .append(MONGO_SET_OPERATOR, finalVar)
  //      .append(MONGO_SET_ON_INSERT_OPERATOR, new Document()
    //   .append("arCtBDFrame", java.util.Arrays.asList(arrayBDFrame)))


    println("updateDocument : " + updateDocument)

    println("updateDocument(json) : " + updateDocument.toJson)
```

Can you please help me?